# Cordova sms plugin

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, sms

I'm writing a visual studio 2015 project with apache Cordova sms plugin. 
I write this litte code

```
function InviaSms()
    {
            var number = document.querySelector("#numberTxt").value;
            var message = document.querySelector("#messageTxt").value;

            //configurazione
            var options = {
                replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
                android: {
                    //intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
                    intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
                }
            };

            var success = function () { $('#erroresms').text = 'Message sent successfully'; };
            var error = function (e) { $('#erroresms').text = e; };

            sms.send(number, message, options, success, error);
    }
```

It's work fine with android platform, but when I deploy it as Windows Phone Universal app sms functionality doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows Universal, it is "cleanest" to do this purely in Javascript see this https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin/issues/31

Comment: Can you give me same indication? I'm a newbie with cordova application. Thanks.

Comment: I write code in windows universal app in javascript